# When `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` returns result different than `OK`?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to create a chatbot with Dialogflow and Google Assistant along with Google Transactions API for enabling a user to order a chocolate box. For now my agent contains the following four intents:

- `Default Welcome Intent` (text response: Hello, do you want to buy a chocolate box?)
- `Default Fallback Intent`
- `Int1` (training phrase: Yes, I want, fulfilment: enabled webhook call)
- `Int2` (event: actions_intent_TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK )

I am using Dialogflow Json instead of Node.js to connect my agent with Transactions API. I want to test that the user meets the transaction requirements (when ordering the chocolate box) by using the `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` action of Google actions. For this reason, following Google docs, when `Int1` is triggered I am using a webhook which connects Google Assistant to the following python script (back-end):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import  requests

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/",  methods=['POST'])

def index():

    data = request.get_json()    
    intent = data["queryResult"]["intent"]["displayName"]

    if (intent == 'Int1'):

        return jsonify({ "data": {
                "google": {
                "expectUserResponse": True,
                "isSsml": False,
                "noInputPrompts": [],
                "systemIntent": {
                  "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionRequirementsCheckSpec",
                    "paymentOptions": {
                      "actionProvidedOptions": {
                        "displayName": "VISA-1234",
                        "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK"
                                }
                        }
                                        }
                })
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'HERE'})

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The result in the json response which I receive after `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` and `Int2` are triggered is:

```
  "arguments": [
                {
                 "extension": {
                                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionRequirementsCheckResult",
                                "resultType": "OK"
                                                   },
                 "name": "TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK_RESULT"
                }
               ]
```

The confusing fact is that even if I send:

```
{
   "displayName": "FALSE",
   "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
                                 }
```

the response is the same which means that it returns again `OK`.
When I send something like this

```
{
   "displayName": "FALSE",
   "paymentType": "WRONG"
                           }
```

then I get an error:

`API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "(payment_options.action_provided_options.payment_type): invalid value "WRONG" for type TYPE_ENUM".`

but this is not exactly given by `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` and `Int2` because these two are not triggered so I do not get any json response back with a result different than `OK`.

**Therefore, my question is: In which cases am I going to receive a result from `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` which is different than `OK`?**

**If I am going to get an `OK` result for anything that I am writing then what is the point of using `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK`?**

P.S.
I have in mind the following about `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` from Google docs:

> Note: The actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK intent is
>   currently under development and will return a success state regardless
>   of the user's payment settings and locale. To test out the failure
>   state scenario, request the intent on a voice-activated speaker.

but still I am not seeing any difference when I using this app on Google Assistant with my voice on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you we have to return to Google docs to solve this. According to Google docs the possible responses of `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` are the following: `RESULT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED`, `OK`, `USER_ACTION_REQUIRED`, `ASSISTANT_SURFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED`, `REGION_NOT_SUPPORTED`
([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRuEc.png)).

Nothing of them has to do exactly with this:

```
            "paymentOptions": {
              "actionProvidedOptions": {
                "displayName": "VISA-1234",
                "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
              }
            }
```

This is also because your back-end cannot (or it is not even allowed to) directly reach the payment details of the user so the json above is only inserted by your back-end if you know them or in a sense you can write whatever you want. This is only for being displayed at the order preview and it is not cross-checked with the payment details of the user's Google account.

In conclusion, `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` may only return a non `OK` status if the result is unspecified (`RESULT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED`) or if the user is expected to take action (`USER_ACTION_REQUIRED`) or if the transactions are not supported on current device/surface (`ASSISTANT_SURFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED`) or if the transactions are not supported for current region/country (`REGION_NOT_SUPPORTED`).